# Bash perl regex not escaping properly

Tags: regex, bash, grep

I have this command:

```
grep -PoRn '(?!.+?\.trigger[\(\s]+[\'\"])([a-zA-Z\:]+)(?>![\'\"])' .
```

But it throws up this:

```
-bash: ![\'\"]: event not found
```

Why? I have single quotes around my regex; I'm using `-P` for perl, I have escaped my single and double quotes, but nae luck.

Bash version is `4.2.25(1)-release` on Ubuntu.

Any ideas? Cheers!

Comment: I tried double escaping the quotes too but it didn't do anything...

Comment: `PoRn` lol grep you're a perv :D

Comment: I also tried escaping both `!`s and it just started running my previous command, as if doing `!!`

Comment: And haha yeah, when I saw that combination of flags I had to order them like that ;)

Comment: \ is escaped with \\\\ (4 of them)

Comment: sorry did'nt noticed that you used -P perl regex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is happening because history expansion happens inside single quotes.

You can get around this by using the `$''` format:

```
grep -PoRn $'(?!.+?\.trigger[\(\s]+[\'\"])([a-zA-Z\:]+)(?>![\'\"])' .
```

From the `bash` man page:

```
   Words of the form $'string' are treated specially.  The word expands to
   string,  with backslash-escaped characters replaced as specified by the
   ANSI C standard.  Backslash escape sequences, if present,  are  decoded
   as follows:
          \a     alert (bell)
          \b     backspace
          \e
          \E     an escape character
          \f     form feed
          \n     new line
          \r     carriage return
          \t     horizontal tab
          \v     vertical tab
          \\     backslash
          \'     single quote
          \"     double quote
          \nnn   the  eight-bit  character  whose value is the octal value
                 nnn (one to three digits)
          \xHH   the eight-bit character whose value  is  the  hexadecimal
                 value HH (one or two hex digits)
          \uHHHH the  Unicode (ISO/IEC 10646) character whose value is the
                 hexadecimal value HHHH (one to four hex digits)
          \UHHHHHHHH
                 the Unicode (ISO/IEC 10646) character whose value is  the
                 hexadecimal value HHHHHHHH (one to eight hex digits)
          \cx    a control-x character
```

Comment: That's the one, I hadn't ever seen that before. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The `!` is being treated as the beginning of a history expansion. You can turn this feature off temporarily with

```
set +H  # Turn history expansion off
grep -PoRn '(?!.+?\.trigger[\(\s]+[\'\"])([a-zA-Z\:]+)(?>![\'\"])' .
set -H  # Turn history expansion back on
```

Rather than turning it off and on unconditionally, you can check the `$-` parameter to see if the `H` option is set:

```
[[ $- = *H* ]]; hist_on=$?   # Is history expansion enabled?
(( hist_on )) && set +H      # Turn it off if it is
grep ...
(( hist_on )) && set -H      # Turn it back on if it was
```

If you are able to run your command in a subshell, you can just turn history expansion off for the subshell; the original setting in the current shell (on or off) will be unchanged.

```
( set +H; grep ... )
```

Comment: Upvote for the `set +H` tip, thanks. I don't really use history expansion much so I may just stick that into my `.bashrc` file.